# Bootstrap CSS messes up collapsible menu z-index?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Basically, I have a site that has a sticky header and sidebar nav but when the screen is made smaller, the menu adopts a hamburger button that can expand the collapsible sidebar.

This works as expected except for one thing: The inclusion of the bootstrap CSS cdn.

So If I comment out the CDN for the bootstrap CSS it works correctly, but If I include it and make the screen mobile size, upon hitting the menu button, the menu expands under the main content cards in the main div. If I comment it out, the menu expands on top of the cards as it should.

IN my codepen above, it has the bootstrap CDN to show the error. I have a custom CSS which is also attached there and I have a lot of styling there, I'm just wondering how I can get this fixed and still have the bootstrap CSS for other stying.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <div class="branding">
    <div class="menu-button menu-toggle nav">
      <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    </div>
    <img src=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="page-details"></div>
  <div class="settings">
    <div class="menu-button profile">
      <i class="material-icons">person</i>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-button menu-toggle aside">
      <i class="material-icons">chat</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="app">
  <nav>
    <div class="title-block">
      <img src=""/>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">home</i>
          <span>Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">adb</i>
          <span>Menu Item with a Long Name</span></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">android</i>
          <span>Android</span></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">attachment</i>
          <span>Attachments</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">bookmark</i>
          <span>Bookmarks</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">star</i>
          <span>Favorites</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">build</i>
          <span>Configuration</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">cake</i>
          <span>Birthday Party</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">brush</i>
          <span>Designer</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="material-icons">camera</i>
          <span>Photos</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!--These are the cards that the menu expands underneath-->
  <article>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Does adding `nav.open {z-index: 999;}` not do the trick?

Comment: It's interesting to me - you mention z-index, but your `nav.open` doesn't have any - all I did is add `z-index` to `nav.open`, and it's on top instead of behind....  (I personally like to use very large numbers - such as 255555 (which is somewhat arbitrary) to try and ensure it's larger than ANY other z-index)

Comment: simply adding `z-index: 1;` to the `nav` fixes it for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `z-index: 9999;` to the `nav.open` worked.

Comment: Not sure how I totally missed this! Thanks very much

Comment: No probs. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Just adding insane numbers to `z-index` is bad practice.

Comment: I'd actually agree with that, but it was safe practice for a solution to a problem in this situation.

Comment: I understand, but [according to Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#z-index), `1071` was enough if even needed :)

Answer (score 2):

nav.open {z-index: 1 !important};

Z-index will allow you to show the nav on top of other elements and the !important will help you overwrite the bootstrap css

Comment: Why not just use proper cascading instead of using the `!important` sledgehammer?